# How to change the direction of Ajax ValidatorCalloutExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolKit ValidatorCalloutExtender on my web page(which is RighttoLeft page), the issue is that the callout popup is always displayed to the right of the textbox I would like to display in Left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_valextender.PopupPosition = ValidatorCalloutPosition.Left;
```